# change specific column in Quasar's table

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, quasar-framework, quasar

How can I change the style of a specific column in Quasar's table?
I read documentation, but I didn't see that how can I change it without defining all columns in the Vue layout's page.

It works but in the first column.

```
<template v-slot:body-cell-name="props">
    <q-td :props="props">
      <div>
        <q-badge color="purple" :label="props.value" />
      </div>
      <div class="my-table-details">
        {{ props.row.details }}
      </div>
    </q-td>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you provided is from the correct [Quasar Docs](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/table#Example--Body-cell-%5Bname%5D-slot).
It works for the first column because the name of the first property is *name* - hence `body-cell-name`.

If in this example you would like to change the fifth column with the property `protein` you would need to call that slot `body-cell-protein`

Comment: I have been trying to use this for the past couple of hours! It was in my face but I could not see it! Thanks.